# Handling errors in Combine (Swift, iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I don't know how to deal with errors in a Combine flow. I would like to be able to catch errors from a Combine function.

**Could anyone help in explaining what I'm doing wrong here and how I should handle *catching* an error with Combine?**

> Note: The function below is just an example to illustrate a case where an error *could* be caught instead of crashing the app.

```
func dataFromURL<T: Decodable>(_ url: String, _ decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> {
    // 1) Example: If the URL is not well-formatted, I would like to /create/raise/return an error (in a Combine way)

    // 2) Instead of the forced unwrapping here, I would also prefer to raise a catchable error if the creation of the request fails
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:url)!)

    // 3) Any kind of example dealing with potential errors, etc

    return urlSession
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
        .tryMap { result -> T in
            return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: result.data)
        }
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
} 

// function in another file:
func result() {
     // I would like to be able to catch or handle errors in this function

     dataFromURL("test").print()   

    // Example : if error 1), else if error 2) etc
}
```

As explained in the comments, I would like to be able to catch any error outside the `dataFromURL` function, but in a "Combine way".

I used a URL data fetching as an example, but it could be with anything else.

What is the recommended way to raise and catch errors with the Combine flow? Is it to return a Publisher with a specific error for example? If so, how can I do it?

---

**EDIT**

Without Combine, I would just have thrown an error, added the `throws` keyword to the function, and would have caught the error in the `result` function.

But I would have expected Combine to have a simpler or more elegant way to achieve this. For example, maybe something that can be thrown at any time:

```
guard <url is valid> else {
    return PublisherError(URLError.urlNotValid)
}
```

And could have been caught like this:

```
dataFromURL
.print()
.onError { error in
   // handle error here
}
.sink { result in
    // no error
}
```

Comment: It depends what you _want_ to do when an error comes down the pipeline. Block it? Use `replaceError`. Receive and respond to it? Use `catch`. Let it flow out the bottom and just print it? Use `sink`. You have not explained what the desired behavior is of your pipeline (still). Have you looked at the error-related operators and thought about them? Start here: http://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsErrorHandlers/operatorserrorhandlers.html

Comment: “This function is just an example to illustrate a case where an error could be caught instead of crashing the app” An error flowing down a pipeline will never crash the app. It’s just a message. If you don’t understand what a Combine error is, read http://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/start/startfailures.html.

Comment: @matt As explained, I would like to catch and handle errors in the ```result``` function, I just don't know how to *raise* them

Comment: You _did_ raise one. You called `.tryMap`. That is a way to send an error down the pipeline (one of many). Any operator with `try` in its name lets you do that. And there are other ways too.

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Okay, but you've left out part of `.sink`. Sink has a `receiveCompletion` parameter that receives the error, and you _can_ "handle the error" there. So in the pipeline you've shown, `.sink` _is_ the equivalent of `.handleError`. — Also, as I said right at the start, you have to ask yourself what you want to have happen further down the pipeline. Sink is the end, but if you handle the error further up, what now? Do want the error to continue down the pipeline, or do you want to block it? I sent you a link to a tutorial _full of examples_ of this kind of thing, documentation _all_ operators.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the `URL(string:)` initializer fails (returning `nil`), you have to decide what error you want to turn that into. Let's say you want to turn it into a `URLError`. So, if `URL(string:)` returns `nil`, create the `URLError` and use a `Fail` publisher to publish it:

```
func jsonContents<T: Decodable>(
    ofUrl urlString: String,
    as type: T.Type,
    decodedBy decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()
) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        let error = URLError(.badURL, userInfo: [NSURLErrorKey: urlString])
        return Fail(error: error).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    return URLSession.shared
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .tryMap { result -> T in
            return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: result.data)
    }
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

But if you really want to shovel more Combine into it, you can use a `Result.Publisher` instead of `Fail`:

```
func jsonContents<T: Decodable>(
    ofUrl urlString: String,
    as type: T.Type,
    decodedBy decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()
) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> {
    return (
        URL(string: urlString)
            .map { Result.success($0) } // This is Optional.map
            ?? Result.failure(URLError(.badURL, userInfo: [NSURLErrorKey: urlString]))
        )
        .publisher
        .flatMap({
            URLSession.shared
                .dataTaskPublisher(for: $0)
                .tryMap { result -> T in
                    return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: result.data)
            }
        })
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

But things get hard to read. We could factor out the use of `Result` into a new operator, `unwrapOrFail(with:)`:

```
extension Publisher {
    func unwrapOrFail<Wrapped>(with error: Failure) -> Publishers.FlatMap<Result<Wrapped, Self.Failure>.Publisher, Self> where Output == Wrapped? {
        return self
            .flatMap ({
                $0
                    .map { Result.success($0).publisher }
                    ?? Result.failure(error).publisher
            })
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
func jsonContents<T: Decodable>(
    ofUrl urlString: String,
    as type: T.Type,
    decodedBy decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()
) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> {
    return Result.success(urlString).publisher
        .map { URL(string: $0) }
        .unwrapOrFail(with: URLError(.badURL, userInfo: [NSURLErrorKey: urlString]))
        .flatMap({
            URLSession.shared
                .dataTaskPublisher(for: $0)
                .tryMap { result -> T in
                    return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: result.data)
            }
        })
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Note, though, that if you make any mistake along the way, you'll probably get an inscrutable error message and have to pick apart your long pipeline to get Swift to tell you what's really wrong.